# How to handle when webpage does not load on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Currently if there is an error retrieving the webpage then soup will not be populated with the page but gets the default return from beautifulsoup.

I am looking for a way to check for this so that if there is an error getting the webpage I can skip a chunk of code like

```python
if soup:
  do stuff
```

but I do not want to terminate all together. Appologies for the newbie inquiry.

```python
def getwebpage(address):
  try:
      user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
      headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
      req = urllib2.Request(address, None, headers)
      web_handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
      error_desc = BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.responses[e.code][0]
      appendlog('HTTP Error: ' + str(e.code) + ': ' + address)
      return
  except urllib2.URLError, e:
      appendlog('URL Error: ' + e.reason[1] + ': ' + address)
      return
  except:
      appendlog('Unknown Error: ' + address)
      return
  return web_handle


def test():
  soup = BeautifulSoup(getwebpage('http://doesnotexistblah.com/'))
  print soup

  if soup:
    do stuff

test()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure the code so that one function encapsulates the entire process of data retrieval from the url, and another that encapsulates the processing of that data:

```
import urllib2, httplib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def append_log(message):
    print message

def get_web_page(address):
    try:
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
        headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
        request = urllib2.Request(address, None, headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=20)
        try:
            return response.read()
        finally:
            response.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        error_desc = httplib.responses.get(e.code, '')
        append_log('HTTP Error: ' + str(e.code) + ': ' +
                  error_desc + ': ' + address)
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        append_log('URL Error: ' + e.reason[1] + ': ' + address)
    except Exception as e:
        append_log('Unknown Error: ' + str(e) + address)

def process_web_page(data):
    if data is not None:
        print BeautifulSoup(data)
    else:
        pass # do something else

data = get_web_page('http://doesnotexistblah.com/')
process_web_page(data)

data = get_web_page('http://docs.python.org/copyright.html')
process_web_page(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = getwebpage('http://doesnotexistblah.com/')
if soup is not None:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)
```

Is that what you're wanting?

Comment: Yes and no, that is what i WANT, but soup is never None, even when fed a bad address...

Comment: When you just `return` from `getwebpage`, it is `None`.